# Quickest way to get to Jersey from Amsterdam

Tags: trains, bookings, islands

What is the best way to get to Jersey from Amsterdam

Comment: Since [Jersey's rail services mostly closed 50 years ago](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Jersey) I'm not sure why the trains tag is appropriate for this question.

Comment: Which Jersey and which Amsterdam ? What country ?

Comment: 1. What have you looked at already and why didn't that work for you? And that is closely related to 2. What defines *best*? Please [edit] your question

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk I don't see how this is relevant. The rail system in the Netherlands and in France are very much alive, and most of a journey by land would lead through these two countries. The question asks about traveling to Jersey, not in Jersey.

Answer (score 2):

Quickest will undoubtably be by air, with a connection in London Gatwick.  You can fly each leg with either British Airways or Easyjet, but Easyjet won't guarantee the connection in Gatwick.

*Best?* That depends on many factors that we can't know.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easyiest solution is by air. There are several possible routes, but i advise you to use the [Google Flight search](https://www.google.ch/flights/#search;f=JER;t=AMS;d=2017-10-08;r=2017-10-12). When you are in Amsterdam, Schiphol Airport, you can take the train to Amsterdam CS (stands for main station). These trains are very easy to find, and there are a lot of signs directing you to them.